# Can i use the mean value theorem here?

Tags: surface-integrals, divergence-theorem, mean-value-theorem

Suppose i have two functions, one of mass flow and other of momentum flow through a surface:
$$ f = \int_A \rho (v \cdot n)dA $$
$$ g = \int_A \rho v (v \cdot n)dA $$

$\rho$ = density of the material
$v$ = velocity through the surface
$n$ = normal vector to the surface
$A$ = area of the surface

Is this allowed?
$$ df = \rho (v \cdot n)dA $$
$$ g = \int vdf $$
$$ v_m f = \int vdf  $$
$$ g = v_mf$$

If not, is there a meaningful way to get $f$ into the integral of $g$?

Comment: No, what you're writing makes no sense. So in the case of $f$ (which is a number, not a function) you're talking not about mass, but about the rate of mass transport across $A$. I do not understand what $g$ means.

Comment: Yes its both mass flow and momentum flow through a surface. Like the 2nd term of the reynolds transport theorem. I clarified it.

Comment: OK, so now your $df$ certainly makes no sense to a mathematician. Independent of your notational issues, I know of no mean-value theorem for vector-valued integrals.

Comment: f is not vector valued, its mass transport, the dot product makes it the whole integral scalar. I will add notations. Maybe this notation is not familiar, but i see this kind of "play" on my physics books quite often. I just want to know if i can do that, and if not, is there any way to relate g with f?

Comment: I understand that $f$ is not vector-valued. Well, don't try to "play" in ways that the physics books don't actually justify.

Comment: Ok , is there any way to relate f and g though?

Comment: What if $A$ is a sphere and $v=n$?

Comment: I understand, so you need extra assumptions to relate them, right? I understand now that the manipulation i did on g makes no sense because there is no MVT for vector valued functions. I was thinking that since the integrands are similar, there would be a general way to fit in one integral into the other. Thanks.